# How to hide the "Add to cart message" on mobile site"?

Tags: commerce, rules, status-messages

I'm using two different themes for main site and mobile site. I want to hide the Add to cart message on mobile site because I've created a custom window with custom messages but I want it to be displayed on the main desktop site. How can I hide it on mobile site?

Comment: Don't you have a specific class on the body tag when you view the site on a mobile device ? A lot of themes does that. If you have that, it's pretty easy to prevent the add to cart to be displayed.

Comment: But I just want to hide the add to cart messages not the whole status messages. By adding a class will hide all the status messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everything for your time. I figured it out this way. 
I put a condition in the show add to cart mesage in rules where I call a function. The function returns false if it's a mobile theme and returns true if it's another theme. Thus it's not showing anymore on the mobile theme :).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use [hook_node_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7) to override the submit handler for `commerce_cart_line_item_views_form_submit`. Check for your theme and apply messages appropriately. However, that will only work for this single message. You would have to rewrite all of the cart functions that have messages.

Another way: I know you can do this with CSS. You just need to target the product pages only. I don't know your CSS structure, but if you look at the classes in the `<body>` element, you should see classes that you can use to cascade down and set `display: none;` to the message region. I don't know what other messages will show up that you care about on the product pages. If you do have some, then the first option is your only option. (Or the non-recommended option below.)

You could also edit the cart source but that is not a good option because it breaks your upgrade path.

If you are using Kickstart, I can find the function to override there as well. (I have sites running both.)